# R2 for dynamic regression model in R

Tags: r, time-series

I'm using prof Hyndman's fpp2 package in R to generate dynamic regression model with auto.arima. I want to see the R2, but it's not shown in the summary output. Just wonder it's not an important metric in dynamic regression? is it possible to quickly generate it?

thank you all.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your summary output?

Comment: Sure, I've attached one output example. Just learnt how to do it...:) .

Comment: Your question  1 is duplicate of this one https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101546/what-is-the-problem-with-using-r-squared-in-time-series-models and your question 2 is off topic answer can be found here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/how-can-i-calculate-the-r-squared-of-a-regression-with-arima-errors-using-r

Answer (score 0):

Per Hyndman, R-squared is not well defined for time series models. See [How can I calculate the R-squared of a regression with arima errors using R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/how-can-i-calculate-the-r-squared-of-a-regression-with-arima-errors-using-r).